# Debuging variables in custom blocks view

Tags: magento2, blocks, debugging, view

Using var_dump to debug manually objects and arrays in custom module causes blank page instead the dump.

What I do wrong?

in View

```
if ($currentProduct = $block->getCurrentProduct()) {
    $variants = $block->getVariants($currentProduct);
    $parent = $block->getCurrentProduct();
    var_dump($parent);
    //blank page

} ?>
```

Comment: plz show your code for more reference. try using $parent->getData()

Comment: Maybe your PHP is running out of memory, or the server hangs trying too display to much data. Try to log it: inject `\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface` and `$logger->debug(\Zend_Debug::dump($parent, null, false))`.

Answer (score 0):

Below is answer given by [Michael Berkowski](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998490/how-to-get-xdebug-var-dump-to-show-full-object-array):

configurable variables in php.ini:

```
; with sane limits
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 5
xdebug.var_display_max_children = 256
xdebug.var_display_max_data = 1024 


; with no limits
; (maximum nesting is 1023)
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = -1 
xdebug.var_display_max_children = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_data = -1
```

These may also be set at runtime via ini_set(), useful if you don't want to modify php.ini and restart your web server but need to quickly inspect something more deeply.

```
ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_depth', 5);
ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_children', 256);
ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_data', 1024);
```

More info [here](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings)